# I want to make a table but its when I want to add a double line, it gives me two tables

Tags: tables

So I tried to make a table using this code:

```
\begin {tabular}{|l||c|p{8cm}|}
\hline
test & test2\\
\hline\hline
test3 & test4\\
\hline\hline
\end {tabular}
```

Between the 2 rows of thext I want to add a double line, but it splits the table in 2. How do I change this? Sorry for my bad english, I hope you guys understand it.

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if you provide a full compilable minimal example instead of a sniplet like this. Then those who want to help do not have to add anything to the example.

Comment: Thanks for both awnsers, I will approve my question the next time. And have a better look through stackexchange before I post question. I am sorry

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: IF you feel the question is duplicated elsewhere on the site, then yes, removal would be appropriate.

Comment: @user3201911 No need either to be sorry or to delete the question. You simply didn't find the answer to your question and now you've find it in the duplicate. :-)